# mk-sbuild error: Package libeatmydata1 is not installed

Tags: linux, deb, debian-packaging

I am trying to compile a few 32 bit debs on my 64 bit Lubuntu (21.10 - Impish Indri). The target is Focal though and I have been trying to build the chroot with mk-sbuild.

The command I ran is `mk-sbuild focal --arch=i386 --debootstrap-include=eatmydata`

But, even after specifically mentioning eat my data, it still stops at:

```
I: Configuring build-essential...
I: Configuring libc-bin...
W: Failure while configuring base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /var/lib/schroot/chroots/focal-i386/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details (possibly the package eatmydata is at fault)
W: Failure while configuring base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /var/lib/schroot/chroots/focal-i386/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details (possibly the package eatmydata is at fault)
W: Failure while configuring base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /var/lib/schroot/chroots/focal-i386/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details (possibly the package eatmydata is at fault)
W: Failure while configuring base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /var/lib/schroot/chroots/focal-i386/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details (possibly the package eatmydata is at fault)
W: Failure while configuring base packages.  This will be re-attempted up to five times.
W: See /var/lib/schroot/chroots/focal-i386/debootstrap/debootstrap.log for details (possibly the package eatmydata is at fault)
```

And, upon checking the log, these are the lines where the problem starts:

```
Setting up g++-9 (9.3.0-10ubuntu2) ...
Setting up g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++ to provide /usr/bin/c++ (c++) in auto mode
Setting up build-essential (12.8ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eatmydata
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eatmydata:
 eatmydata depends on libeatmydata1 (>= 105-7); however:
  Package libeatmydata1 is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package eatmydata (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eatmydata
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eatmydata:
 eatmydata depends on libeatmydata1 (>= 105-7); however:
  Package libeatmydata1 is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package eatmydata (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eatmydata
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eatmydata:
 eatmydata depends on libeatmydata1 (>= 105-7); however:
  Package libeatmydata1 is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package eatmydata (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eatmydata
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of eatmydata:
 eatmydata depends on libeatmydata1 (>= 105-7); however:
  Package libeatmydata1 is not installed.
 
dpkg: error processing package eatmydata (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 eatmydata
```

After trying both `pbuilder` and `debuild` I thought sbuild might be the only viable option to build 32 bit debs on a bit OS. But, it's not easy too.

By the way, the 64 bit build goes fine and doesn't ask for eatmydata at all.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Package libeatmydata1 is not installed" : If that means a missing 32bit version : It's not available https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/libeatmydata1

Comment: @KnudLarsen This is confusing as the build goes fine on Focal. I tried compiling a few debs for Impish on Focal with an Impish chroot. Surprisingly, it is able to build fine. I don't understand why eatmydata isn't available in Impish. Anyways, any ideas on how to bypass this issue? And, I am sorry for the late reply.

Comment: ? You might use the 18.04 package https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libeatmydata1 → i386.

Comment: @KnudLarsen How do I add it to the list of packages in mk-sbuild. Had the chroot been built, I could have manually installed it using `sbuild-shell`